# IllegalArgumentException: Parameter valuefunction.AggregationFunction did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to increment my variable via criteria builder.  I wrote the following code

```
    final CriteriaBuilder cb= getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaUpdate<MyEntity> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(MyEntity.class);
    final Root<MyEntity> root = update.from(MyEntity.class);

    update.set("field", cb.sum(criteriaBuilder.<Long>sum(root.get("field"), 1L)));
    update.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), id));

    final Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(update);
    query.executeUpdate();
```

MyEntity:

```
@Table(name ="myEntity")
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
private String id;
private long field;
}
```

Database table has the following structure:

```
  create table if not exists myEntity
(
    field integer not null,
    id varchar(32) not null,
);
```

But I've got the following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value
>   [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.function.AggregationFunction$SUM@46dd740b]
>   did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]

How can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code.

First: you select the wrong overload.

```
CriteriaUpdate<T> set(String attributeName, Object value);
```

instead of:

```
<Y> CriteriaUpdate<T> set(
        Path<Y> attribute,
        Expression<? extends Y> value);
```

This is because you use untyped CriteriaBuilder. The way to solve it is to pass the first argument as a `Path<Long>`, not `String`.

Second:
I'm not sure what your query is trying to accomplish, but it looks there is one sum to many. I believe it should look like:

```
Path<Long> fieldPath = root.get("field");
update.set (fieldPath, cb.sum(root.get("field"), 1L));
update.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), id));
```

Which will generate:

```
update
    my_entity 
set
    field=field+1 
where
    id=?"
```